# Vue abbreviation not working in VS code with Emmet

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, emmet

I am learning vue and using VS code, I am trying to fix an issue in VS code, if I type vue and press tab I am not getting the boilerplate code like shown in this [video](https://youtu.be/bc6czIBLKTg?si=U0weCk7K95P1Kjd0&t=2189) at 3:29, I found some solutions like adding some code in settings.json file but none of them worked, I even reinstalled VS code but the issue remains, I added these lines to my settings file :

```
 "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
  "files.associations": {
      "*html": "html",
      "*njk": "html"
  },
  "emmet.useInlineCompletions": true,
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
       "javascript": "javascriptreact",
       "typescript": "typescriptreact",
       "vue-html": "html",
       "vue": "html",
       "razor": "html",
       "plaintext": "pug",
       "django-html": "html"
 },
 "emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": true,
 "emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "always",
```

None of these worked.

Comment: Which version of VueJS do you use? For Vue3 you need to install the [Volar Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vue.volar). For Vue2 you can use the [Vetur Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur). Maybe that's missing for you? By default, the code editor does not know which language / framework a `.vue` file is and also doesn't have any autocompletions for it.

Comment: @AlexBerger I use Vue3 and Volar extension is installed.

Comment: I reinstalled VSCode and all extensions, the abbreviation/IntelliSense works with Vetur but not Volar for some reason.